# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi' Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python

I need some help I cannot seem to get this to work. Any Ideas?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/SeniorDesign/demo $ python servotest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "servotest.py", line 3, in <module>
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'

pi@raspberrypi:~/SeniorDesign/demo $ sudo apt-get install python-dev python-rpi.gpio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-dev is already the newest version (2.7.16-1).
python-rpi.gpio is already the newest version (0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
pi@raspberrypi:~/SeniorDesign/demo $ pip freeze | grep RPi
RPi.GPIO==0.7.0

pi@raspberrypi:~/SeniorDesign/demo $ sudo apt-get install python3-rpi.gpio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-rpi.gpio is already the newest version (0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

pi@raspberrypi:~/SeniorDesign/demo $ apt-cache pkgnames | grep rpi.gpio
python-rpi.gpio-dbgsym
python3-rpi.gpio
rpi.gpio-common
python-rpi.gpio
python3-rpi.gpio-dbgsym
```

Comment: **DO NOT** post pictures of text post text

Comment: I see no code. DO NOT fiddle with text just insert a copy and use code formatting tool {}

Comment: What happens if you use ‘python3 servotest.py’ ?

Comment: ‘python3 servotest.py’ gives me the same error

Comment: @CoderMike You did give me a good Idea. I tried ‘python2 servotest.py’ and it worked. I wonder why that is happening if I got python 3.8

Comment: I would suspect installing Python 3.8 has broken something. Why did you install python 3.8? I would restart with a fresh install of Raspberry Pi OS and stick to python 3.7

Comment: So installing python 3.8 was the problem for sure. I reinstalled raspberry pi os again and it works fine now. no need to update anything. It came with the proper updates. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

First, determine you're using the correct python and pip with `which python` and `which pip`. There is a bit of ambiguity with python3 and pip3. If you have not already aliased python3 for python and pip3 for pip then you might be using the older versions of them.

Check to make sure you don't have redundancies with where your packages are being downloaded to as well. For example, there are ~/.local repos as well as the roots repos. This can easily lead to confusion as well. You want to make sure that all packages are either globally available/ are on your Python $PATH.

Comment: With which python I get /usr/bin/python, and which pip I get /usr/bin/pip

Comment: @JoeCodes Okay, good. What do you get with `which python3` and `which pip3`?

Comment: To avoid confusing it is simple to just only use `python3` and `pip3`, never mention to use `python` or `pip`.

Comment: @Ingo Good point, it's just that there is still ambiguity in the community between the two. This is just due to python 2 being deprecated of course. Some people alias the versions (which really only adds to confusion). Until there is a more clear standardization, it is best to explicitly state version, as you suggested.